# jquery $ is not defined despite that jquery loaded before main.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use smoothstate.js, dispte that my jquery cdn is before my main.js it still give me an error $ is not defined

My scripts loading order:

```
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Smoothstate.js -->
    <script src="../assets/scritps/jquery.smoothState.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script tags -->
    <script src="../assets/scritps/main.js"></script>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
'use strict';
var $page = $('#main'),
    options = {
      debug: true,
      prefetch: true,
      cacheLength: 2,
      onStart: {
        duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
        render: function ($container) {
          // Add your CSS animation reversing class
          $container.addClass('is-exiting');
          // Restart your animation
          smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
        }
      },
      onReady: {
        duration: 0,
        render: function ($container, $newContent) {
          // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
          $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
          // Inject the new content
          $container.html($newContent);
        }
      }
    },
    smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Comment: try `https://ajax.googleapis.c...` once instead of `//ajax.googleapis.c`

Comment: sorry it didn't work

Comment: Try `jQuery(function(){...});` instead of `$(function(){...});` in case there's a collision for the `$` symbol.